# Nested entity into one DTO object automapper. Unable to figure out the correct mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Here's my main entity which I want to convert to a DTO.

My entity is

```
public class ServiceBillingInformation
{

    public DateRange EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

My DTO is

```
public class ServiceBillingModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

How do I map the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of the DTO to the `EffectiveDate.StartDate` and `EffectiveDate.EndDate` respectively?

I have tried many mappings and I always get the mapping errors on `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid` method.

Comment: `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid` messages usually are quite descriptive. Why just not to follow them? Post the error message if help is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple one way mapping would look like

```
Mapper.Initialize( t => 
    t.CreateMap< ServiceBillingInformation, ServiceBillingModel>()
    .ForMember( d => d.StartDate, f =>  f.MapFrom( src => src.EffectiveDate.StartDate ))
    .ForMember( d => d.EndDate, f => f.MapFrom(src => src.EffectiveDate.EndDate))
    );
```